# What is the optimal strategy for this 2 player game?

Tags: probability, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Let some finite array of integers is given initially.

There is a number k which is initially '0'.

In a move, a player will select a number from the array arr[i] and change k to gcd(k,arr[i]).

Also, the number chosen from the array(i.e a[i]) will be removed from that array.

CONSTRAINTS

A player who makes k=1 at any step loses.
A player who cannot move also loses.
2 players are playing the game optimally.

When will the player who moves first wins the game?

Comment: I assume that for the first step, gcd(0,N)=N?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes,gcd(0,N)=N.

Comment: This question is from an ongoing contest.. do it yourself .. don't ask for help

Comment: @reddy Which contest? Can you provide us a link to confirm this?

Comment: @reddy I asked for a reference for the contest, and so has Alex Becker now, if you don't provide a reference, I would not hold it against anyone for answering the question.